# How do I grab the icon of apps on an specific URL

Tags: wget, curl

Consider [this URL](http://apps.apple.com/app/id1065138311).

When you visit that page you see the app's icon at the top left.

I have a lot of pages like that that I want to grab the icon.
I am writing an article for a blog and I need these icons.

I have tried

```
 wget -nd -r -P . -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://apps.apple.com/app/id1065138311
```

and

```
curl http://apps.apple.com/app/id1065138311
```

hoping I could download every element on that page but apparently that page has some sort of mechanism that prevents curl and wget to work.

I am using macOS Catalina.

I just want the images.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I want to talk about these apps and I need their icons.

Comment: From the page source: `https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple30/v4/d2/11/fd/d211fd05-57a7-95fa-a2f3-e37c59dc3578/pr_source.png/246x0w.png`

Comment: You can take a screenshot too, and crop the image in Preview or any other app...

Comment: @Philippe, no, this one https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple30/v4/d2/11/fd/d211fd05-57a7-95fa-a2f3-e37c59dc3578/pr_source.png/246x0w.png